# Request body stream exhausted when using Parse's saveInBackgroundWithBlock:

Tags: ios, parse-platform, objective-c-blocks

The problem only happens when I have using mobile data to upload photo to Parse that I will get "Upload Failure - Request Body Stream exhausted" error. That means if my phone is using WiFi mode, everything goes smooth.

Anyone could help me to solve the problem?

Thanks,
Kenny

My code for saving image is attached below:

```
self.pfProfile[@"logo"] = imageFile;


// Upload Profile to Parse
[self.pfProfile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    [indicator stopAnimating];
    if (succeeded) {
        NSLog(@"Update Profile Successfully");
        // Notify table view to reload the recipes from Parse cloud
        //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshTable" object:self];
    } else {
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                              alertControllerWithTitle:@"Upload Failure" message:[error localizedDescription]
                                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *okayAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
        [alertController addAction:okayAction];
        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}];
```

Comment: It looks like a problem with file size... can you please post the code you are using for uploading the photo to Parse, and also specify the approximate file size?

Comment: The image is captured from imagePicker with size 300x300.

Comment: how'd you fixed this? @KennyChoi